# Ogre3D - render water with waves by vertex? nurbs?

Tags: vertex, ogre3d, nurbs

I have an Ogre3D application and I would like to render a surface that represents the water with waves. 
I think I am not the only one that has this purpose, so I was looking for an example to follow.
I imagine that if I want to create a water surface and want to move it like a wave I have to create a surface with many vertexes (according to which precision I want) and then control the height of each vertexes.
As the water will be quite big, I think that the water will take long time to be rendered, so I was wandering  if it was better to render it by vertex or nurbs? Or are there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

There's an Ocean example included in Ogre distribution that you can use as starting point. I don't remember if it uses any LOD system but it has quite nice random waves and Fresnel shader.

The nurbs won't help you much as there's no easy way to push them into GPU. They're good for some modelling tasks but at the end you need to convert them to 'real' geometry.